# Rust constraints for generic types Item

Tags: rust

While looking through the documentation for [flatten](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Flatten.html).

```
pub struct Flatten<I> 
where
    I: Iterator,
    <I as Iterator>::Item: IntoIterator,
```

I was wondering why this is needed -- the last line.
Would the following not be sufficient?

```
I::Item: IntoIterator,
```

After all `I` is constrained to be `Iterator` on the line before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not necessary, indeed, and [the actual code uses completely another form](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.63.0/src/core/iter/adapters/flatten.rs.html#150) (an unstable `Trait<Assoc: Trait>` syntax, similar to the equality syntax `Trait<Assoc = Type>`). It is just rustdoc showing that, because in theory you could have a type parameter implementing two traits that both have the same associated item.